# Three month old only sleeps 10-11 hours a day

Tags: infant, sleep

Our third seems to be way more active than average baby (comparing to the previous two), all and all he hits his developmental goals so far very well.

One thing that worries me is his sleep. He sleeps 8 hours at night like a normal adult. When it turns dark he goes to sleep, and when Sun comes up he wakes everyone up and has no intention of sleeping longer than necessary...

During day he sleeps 4-5 times around 15-30 minutes every time and wakes up not due to noise (most of the time), but by himself (he usually spends some time playing with his fingers or just looking around before making noise and calling us).

His sleep is way under normal 13-16 hours, [I have checked some statistical data](https://www.parentingscience.com/baby-sleep-chart.html) and he falls near 95% percentile, we are white but live in Asia so I am not sure should I take one hour away. Whole thing is becomming worrisome, since sleep is considered essential in normal development.

**What am I looking at? Should I take action?**

Comment: You should ask your doctor.  They will be far better at evaluating what is going on and what you should do than the random people on the internet.

Comment: I wouldn't even bother asking a doctor about this one. Your baby sounds totally fine. "hours a day" is just a general expectation based on averages. If your baby took no naps and was very hard to get to sleep I would consider a doctor. But sleep at night, 4-5 naps a day? You got it easy. Kick back and relax 4-5 times a day and enjoy your full night's sleep. Hell that practically makes you a Czar of parents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that "95% percentile" means 1 baby in 20 will be like that. Probably nothing to worry about if there are no symptoms that he's not getting the sleep he needs (growth, development, mood, etc). Perhaps if he's being breastfed, make sure mom is not drinking too much coffee.

Bottom line: stop looking up charts on the internet, it's not good for you ;-)

Comment: Psh. this deserves to be upvoted entirely because of the last line alone, no matter what anyone thinks. Stop reading dr. internet and consult a physician when you have concerns

Comment: There is something worse for a baby than lack of sleep that has no impact on mood etc. : Anxious parents.

Comment: Definitely. Insanity spreads. If you want your kid to be nervous, defiant, rude, mean, etc. Just do it yourself. Stay calm and be what you'd like for them.

Answer (score 0):

As long as he's healthy and eating/playing fine and is not cranky/upset in the active hours, please don't bother too much about his sleep.

Some infants sleep for 14 hours while a few sleep only 9-10 hours a day. These sleep hours may not match with averages which you see online but that's okay, each child is different.

Even in older kids, we see this pattern. Some of them fall asleep at the same time everyday irrespective of their activity levels and some others can't sleep unless they are physically tired.